# (C/C++, Windows) Issues with AttachConsole and FreeConsole only working once

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, signals

I'm trying to send a ctrl+C signal to the console of another process when a button is clicked, by attaching the current process to its console, sending a ctrl+C signal, then freeing the current process from a console. This works fine the first time, but doesn't do anything the second time.

```
void abort(){
    AttachConsole(processInfo.dwProcessId); //processInfo is of type PROCESS_INFORMATION
    SetConsoleCtrlHandler(0, true);
    GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent(CTRL_C_EVENT, 0);
    FreeConsole();
}
```

Also, even manually clicking in the console and pressing ctrl+C works the first time but not the second. Closing the console manually always works.

process.exe is a child process, and is created in exactly the same way as in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10888698/2805328).

---

Full code to recreate the problem (using Qt 4.8 with vs2010 compiler on windows 10 for gui/threading):

main.cpp:

```
#include "dialog.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    Dialog w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

dialog.h:

```
#ifndef DIALOG_H
#define DIALOG_H

#include <QDialog>
#include "ui_dialog.h"
#include "worker.h"

namespace Ui {
class Dialog;
}

class Dialog : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Dialog(QWidget *parent = 0):
        QDialog(parent),
        ui(new Ui::Dialog),
        w(new worker()),
        t(new QThread(this))
    {
        ui->setupUi(this);
        connect(ui->startButton, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), this, SLOT(startProcess()));
        connect(ui->abortButton, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), this, SLOT(abortProcess()));
        connect(w, SIGNAL(finished()), t, SLOT(quit()));

        w->setup(t);
        w->moveToThread(t);
    }

    ~Dialog(){delete ui;}

private slots:
    void startProcess(){
        t->start();
    }

    void abortProcess(){
        w->abort();
        t->quit();
    }

private:
    Ui::Dialog *ui;
    worker *w;
    QThread *t;

};

#endif // DIALOG_H
```

worker.h:

```
#ifndef WORKER_H
#define WORKER_H

#include <QDebug>
#include <QObject>
#include <QThread>
#include <Windows.h>

class worker : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit worker(QObject *parent = 0):QObject(parent){}
    void setup(QThread *t){
        connect(t, SIGNAL(started()), this, SLOT(startProcess()));
    }
    void abort(){
        if(!AttachConsole(p.dwProcessId)) qDebug() << "AttachConsole" << GetLastError();
        if(!SetConsoleCtrlHandler(0, true)) qDebug() << "SetConsoleCtrlHandler" << GetLastError();
        if(!GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent(CTRL_C_EVENT, 0)) qDebug() << "GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent" << GetLastError();
        if(!FreeConsole()) qDebug() << "FreeConsole" << GetLastError();
    }

private slots:
    void startProcess(){
        ZeroMemory(&p, sizeof(p));
        STARTUPINFOA s;
        SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sec;
        HANDLE read = NULL;
        HANDLE write = NULL;

        ZeroMemory(&sec, sizeof(sec));
        sec.nLength = sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES);
        sec.bInheritHandle = true;
        sec.lpSecurityDescriptor = NULL;

        if(!CreatePipe(&read, &write, &sec, 0)) qDebug() << "CreatePipe error" << GetLastError();
        if(!SetHandleInformation(read, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0)) qDebug() << "SetHandleInformation error" << GetLastError();

        ZeroMemory(&s, sizeof(s));
        s.cb = sizeof(s);
        s.hStdOutput = write;
        s.hStdError = write;
        s.hStdInput = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
        s.dwFlags |= STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;

        if(!CreateProcessA("helloworld.exe", "helloworld", NULL, NULL, true, CREATE_NO_WINDOW, NULL, NULL, &s, &p)) qDebug() << "CreateProcessA error " << GetLastError() << "\n";

        CloseHandle(write);

        char buff[65];
        DWORD bytesRead;

        while(true){
            if(!ReadFile(read, buff, 64, &bytesRead, NULL)){
                qDebug() << "ReadFile error";
                break;
            }
            if(bytesRead > 0){
                buff[64] = '\0';
                qDebug() << QByteArray(buff);
            }
        }

        CloseHandle(p.hProcess);
        CloseHandle(p.hThread);

        emit finished();
    }

private:
    PROCESS_INFORMATION p;

signals:
    void finished();

};

#endif // WORKER_H
```

The UI just contains 2 buttons, startButton and abortButton. helloworld.exe is just a program that prints "Hello world!" and then waits for input. When startButton is clicked, the process is created, and the output is redirected to my program correctly. When abortButton is clicked, the process is terminated correctly. startProcess works perfectly the second time as well, but now, clicking abortButton does not work. The abort() function is called, and no error messages are printed, but the helloworld process fails to terminate, and the QThread t does not quit.

Comment: I don't see any error checking. How can you be so sure that any of these function calls actually succeed?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I've checked the values returned by the functions, they are all not zero, meaning they succeeded.

Comment: The documentation of `AttachConsole` does suggest that you can only attach to _other_ consoles after calling `FreeConsole`. But that suggestion might be unintended; usually such restrictions are spelled out explicitly.

Comment: *"Works"* and *"doesn't work"* are too fuzzy to make anything of it. From the sounds of it, though, it appears that this other process is the problem (as evidenced by the manual test). Anyway, you need to properly spell out the expected behavior as well as the observed behavior.

Comment: @IInspectable well I'm not sure what you're expecting, but the expected behaviour is that calling abort() will send ctrl+c to the processes console and close it, and the observed behaviour is that that happens correctly the first time I run the process, but after that nothing happens.

Comment: I expected to see some sort of evidence, that sending the signal fails, or attaching to the console fails, or that the other process simply fails to respond to it. There are most likely other ways for this to fail. Your description isn't any more helpful than saying *"something went wrong"*.

Comment: @IInspectable What do you mean "evidence"? How am I supposed to give evidence, when as I said before, all of the function calls return nonzero and don't give any error messages?

Comment: At this point I think we need a [mcve] to make any progress.  Can you reproduce the issue with a built-in child process, e.g., `findstr.exe` ?  That would simplify things.

Comment: @HarryJohnston I've added a complete example to the original post.

Comment: Your MCVE as posted still has the bug that I already pointed out.  I've added some working code to my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the symptoms you describe, my psychic debugging powers tell me that the target process ("process.exe") is a child of your process.  Assuming that to be the case, this is your problem:

```
SetConsoleCtrlHandler(0, true);
```

As described in [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686016(v=vs.85).aspx):

> If the HandlerRoutine parameter is NULL, a TRUE value causes the calling process to ignore CTRL+C input, and a FALSE value restores normal processing of CTRL+C input. **This attribute of ignoring or processing CTRL+C is inherited by child processes.**

(Emphasis mine.)  This means that the child processes are being launched with the option to ignore control-C already turned on.

Instead of configuring the process to ignore control-C altogether, assign a control-C handler function that returns `TRUE`; such a handler will not be inherited by child processes.  Alternatively, if your application is single-threaded, you could just restore the normal configuration before exiting abort():

```
SetConsoleCtrlHandler(0, FALSE);
```

---

You have now posted a MCVE.  Note that I don't have Qt installed, so I had to simplify the code in order to test it.  It was easy enough to reproduce the problem caused by the abort() function disabling control-C processing, but as soon as I corrected that, the code worked perfectly.  Here is the simplified and corrected code, which works perfectly on my system:

```
#include <Windows.h>

void fail(char *msg)
{
    MessageBoxA(NULL, msg, "Oops", MB_OK);
    ExitProcess(1);
}

PROCESS_INFORMATION p;

BOOL WINAPI HandlerRoutine(
  _In_ DWORD dwCtrlType
)
{
    if (dwCtrlType == CTRL_C_EVENT) return TRUE;
    return FALSE;
}


void abortProcess(void)
{
    static BOOL handler_assigned = FALSE;
    if (handler_assigned)
    {
        if (!SetConsoleCtrlHandler(HandlerRoutine, false)) fail("Removing handler routine failed");
    }
    if (!AttachConsole(p.dwProcessId)) fail("AttachConsole");
    if (!SetConsoleCtrlHandler(HandlerRoutine, true)) fail("SetConsoleCtrlHandler");
    handler_assigned = TRUE;
    if (!GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent(CTRL_C_EVENT, 0)) fail("GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent");
    if (!FreeConsole()) fail("FreeConsole");
}

DWORD WINAPI startProcess(LPVOID * dummy)
{
    ZeroMemory(&p, sizeof(p));
    STARTUPINFOA s;
    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sec;
    HANDLE read = NULL;
    HANDLE write = NULL;

    ZeroMemory(&sec, sizeof(sec));
    sec.nLength = sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES);
    sec.bInheritHandle = true;
    sec.lpSecurityDescriptor = NULL;

    if(!CreatePipe(&read, &write, &sec, 0)) fail("CreatePipe error");
    if(!SetHandleInformation(read, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0)) fail("SetHandleInformation error");

    ZeroMemory(&s, sizeof(s));
    s.cb = sizeof(s);
    s.hStdOutput = write;
    s.hStdError = write;
    s.hStdInput = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
    s.dwFlags |= STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;

    if(!CreateProcessA("test1.exe", "helloworld", NULL, NULL, true, CREATE_NO_WINDOW, NULL, NULL, &s, &p)) 
    {
        fail("CreateProcessA error ");
    }

    CloseHandle(write);

    char buff[65];
    DWORD bytesRead;

    while(true){
        if(!ReadFile(read, buff, 64, &bytesRead, NULL)){
            DWORD dw = GetLastError();
            if (dw == 0x0000006d) break;
            fail("ReadFile error");
        }
        if(bytesRead > 0){
            buff[64] = '\0';
            MessageBoxA(NULL, buff, "Output", MB_OK);
        }
    }

    MessageBox(NULL, L"Child has exited", L"Good news", MB_OK);
    CloseHandle(p.hProcess);
    CloseHandle(p.hThread);
    return 0;
}

int CALLBACK WinMain(
  _In_ HINSTANCE hInstance,
  _In_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
  _In_ LPSTR     lpCmdLine,
  _In_ int       nCmdShow
)
{
    HANDLE thread;

    for (;;)
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Press OK to launch child", L"so39616404", MB_OK);
        thread = CreateThread(NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)startProcess, NULL, 0, NULL);
        if (thread == NULL) fail("CreateThread error");
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Press OK to kill child", L"so39616404", MB_OK);
        abortProcess();
        if (WaitForSingleObject(thread, INFINITE) != WAIT_OBJECT_0) fail("Wait error");
    }
}
```

Note that it proved necessary to reconfigure the handler routine after attaching to each new console, otherwise the parent process died along with the child when the control-C was generated.  I'm not sure whether it is actually necessary to remove the handler routine before re-adding it, but it seems safest.

If your MCVE still doesn't work, please edit your post to show the corrected version.  (There *might* be some sort of undesired interaction with Qt, I suppose.)

Comment: Yes, process.exe is a child process. I changed that line to `SetConsoleCtrlHandler(0, false);`, added a `bool f(DWORD){return true;}` function, and added `SetConsoleCtrlHandler((PHANDLER_ROUTINE)f, false);` in main, and I'm still getting the same behaviour as before. I've added a link to the first post that shows how the child process is being created, in case that's the problem.

Comment: Thanks! Adding the handler routine function correctly solved the problem. I am having a different, quite strange, problem now though, in that the main process also terminates unless I add a `qDebug() << "some text";` line immediately after calling GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent...

Comment: That *does* sound like an interaction with Qt, you might need someone familiar with the framework to help with that.  Perhaps post a new question, making sure to include the MCVE and to tag it appropriately.  In case it helps, though, I did find that the parent died if I removed the handler too soon - that's why my code doesn't do so until the next call to abortProcess().

Comment: ... perhaps abortProcess() should block until the call to HandlerRoutine() has been made?  You could do that using an event object, probably best to use a native one rather than Qt.