# Boost.Process - reading from process with sleeping loop

Tags: c++, boost-asio, boost-process

I have certain problem and I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

```
//sleeper.exe

int main()
{
  int i = 0;
  while (true)
  {
    printf("%i\n", ++i);
    sleep_for(1s);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

I want to capture sleeper's output in my application and add it line by line to some container;

```
//application.exe

int main()
{
  io_context context;
  async_pipe out(context);
  child sleeper("sleeper.exe", std_out > out, context);      

  vector<string> lines;
  streambuf buffer;
  async_read_until(out, buffer, '\n', [](const error_code& code, size_t size)
  {
    // Add line to container
  });

  context.run();

  return 0;
}
```

Unfortunately my application hangs on `context.run()`, probably because sleeper application never terminates. But it should read sleeper's output until delimiter, so I do not know what is the problem here. I am looking forward some explanation.

**Edit after more research on topic:**

According to: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/190351/how-to-spawn-console-processes-with-redirected-standard-handles

> Note Child processes that use such C run-time functions as printf() and fprintf() can behave poorly when redirected. The C run-time functions maintain separate IO buffers. When redirected, these buffers might not be flushed immediately after each IO call. As a result, the output to the redirection pipe of a printf() call or the input from a getch() call is not flushed immediately and delays, sometimes-infinite delays occur. This problem is avoided if the child process flushes the IO buffers after each call to a C run-time IO function. Only the child process can flush its C run-time IO buffers. A process can flush its C run-time IO buffers by calling the fflush() function.

I am still looking for solution in this field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed you sleeper program doesn't terminate. `run()` will run till completion.

Let's first make the sample "real" so it has an actual read loop to read more than 1 line:

```
std::vector<std::string> lines;

boost::asio::streambuf buffer;

std::function<void()> read_loop;
read_loop = [&] {
    boost::asio::async_read_until(out, buffer, "\n", [&](boost::system::error_code code, std::size_t size) {
        if (code) {
            std::cerr << "Oops: " << code.message() << std::endl;
        } else {
            std::cerr << "received: " << size << " bytes" << std::endl;

            auto b = buffers_begin(buffer.data()), m = b+size;
            lines.emplace_back(b, m);

            buffer.consume(size);

            if (lines.size()<10) {
                read_loop();
            }
        }
    });
};

read_loop();

context.run();
```

You can see that it tries to read 10 lines.

### Terminating the child

You can either kill it:

```
if (lines.size()<10) {
    read_loop();
} else {
    c.terminate();
}
```

Or close the output pipe, causing the same (broken pipe):

```
if (lines.size()<10) {
    read_loop();
} else {
    out.close();
}
```

### Deno

I can't make it work on Coliru, but I replaced first.exe with:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <random>

using namespace std;
static mt19937 prng{random_device{}()};
static auto l() { return uniform_int_distribution(5,20)(prng); }
static auto c() { return uniform_int_distribution('a','z')(prng); }

int main() {
    while(true) {
        cout << std::string(l(), c()) << endl;
        this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(1));
    }
}
```

And with the above program, in full:

```
#include <boost/process.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/process/async.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <regex>

int main() {
    namespace bp = boost::process;
    using namespace std::string_literals;
    boost::asio::io_context context;
    bp::async_pipe out(context);

    bp::child c("./first.exe", bp::std_out > out, context);

    std::vector<std::string> lines;

    boost::asio::streambuf buffer;

    std::function<void()> read_loop;
    read_loop = [&] {
        boost::asio::async_read_until(out, buffer, "\n", [&](boost::system::error_code code, std::size_t size) {
            if (code) {
                std::cerr << "Oops: " << code.message() << std::endl;
            } else {
                std::cerr << "received: " << size << " bytes" << std::endl;

                auto b = buffers_begin(buffer.data()), m = b+size;
                lines.emplace_back(b, m);

                buffer.consume(size);

                if (lines.size()<10) {
                    read_loop();
                } else {
                    c.terminate();
                }
            }
        });
    };

    read_loop();
    context.run();

    for (auto& line : lines) {
        std::cout << std::quoted(std::regex_replace(line, std::regex("\\n"), "\\n"s)) << "\n";
    }

    return c.exit_code();
}
```

Printed, on my system:

```
received: 19 bytes
received: 12 bytes
received: 20 bytes
received: 16 bytes
received: 6 bytes
received: 6 bytes
received: 20 bytes
received: 13 bytes
received: 16 bytes
received: 21 bytes
"dddddddddddddddddd\\n"
"lllllllllll\\n"
"jjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjj\\n"
"uuuuuuuuuuuuuuu\\n"
"yyyyy\\n"
"wwwww\\n"
"hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh\\n"
"qqqqqqqqqqqq\\n"
"aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\\n"
"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\\n"
```

Comment: Added a (non-live) demo.

Comment: To be honest, the code you have provided works with example with random distribution but does not work with my "first.exe". This is really weird. Do you have any suggestions?

Edit: I have updated my example code, it turned out I have been using printf instead of cout. I think that it is related with flushing buffer. How can I handle such situation?

Comment: The same behaviour can be observed when first.exe prints in such way: std::cout << i << "\n";

Comment: It works with your first.exe for me too (but it was a very poor example for reading line-wise, so I changed it up). Yes, there will be standard output buffering depending on your OS and libc (see also `setvbuf`, `stdbuf` and `unbuffer` utilities).

Comment: None of that should matter in any way that you talked about, because you didn't say anything at all about the timing of receipts. And since the program keeps printing regularly, eventually the buffer will be flushed and received regardless of platform specifics and you will read the line(s) in you program. Nothing you said talked about timing requirements. Prevent buffering in any of the ways mentioned and supported on your platform if you want to get more immediate input from the child process.